# How to remove all values in a list in redis?

Tags: nosql, redis

I have a list lst which has values say

```
1.hi
2.hi
3.hello
4.hello
5.sfk
```

I need to remove all these values from the list.What is the easiest way to achieve this ?

```
LREM mylist 0 "hi"
```

I tried the above , but it deletes only hi but i need to delete all values in one shot.
How to achieve this ?
I am new to redis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`DEL`](http://redis.io/commands/del) is probably what you're looking for:

```
redis> RPUSH mylist "hi" "hi" "hello" "hello" "sfk"
(integer) 5
redis> LRANGE mylist 0 -1
1) "hi"
2) "hi"
3) "hello"
4) "hello"
5) "sfk"
redis> DEL mylist
(integer) 1
redis> LRANGE mylist 0 -1
(empty list or set)
```

It returns the number of keys removed.

It takes `O(N)` time where `N` is the number of elements in the list.